# How can I do user input times word.Add

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I want to create a List with words and later compare them. First I need is to add strings to List for wordsnumber times. If user inputs wordsnumber = 5, how can I write that ?

```
 while (wordsnumber < 1 || wordsnumber > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*Leader Instructor: You must follow my instructions !");
                Console.Write("Your number: ");
                wordsnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            if(wordsnumber >= 1 || wordsnumber < 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*Leader Instructor: Awesome.");
            }
            List<string> words = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Do you mean you need to ask the user to input `wordsnumber` words? A simple `for` loop would accomplish that; `for (int i = 0; i < wordsnumber; i++) { Console.Write("Enter word:"); words.Add(Console.ReadLine()); }`

Comment: Shouldn't the `if` condition be `wordsnumber >= 1 && wordsnumber <= 20`? And you don't really need that since the `while` loop wouldn't exit unless it was `true`...

Comment: You should use `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, so you can handle non-numeric input without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal `for` loop to ask the user to enter `wordsNumber` amount of words. Normally the structure of the `for` loop would look something like:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < wordsnumber; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter word #{i + 1}: ");
    words.Add(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

---

A couple other things: you should use `int.TryParse` to try to get the number so the program doesn't crash if they enter some non-numeric text, and you don't need the `if` condition since the `while` loop is already enforcing a valid range of numbers. Just for fun, I also showed how to color the leader instructor text in red, so it stands out more:

```
int wordsnumber;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of words (1 - 20): ");

while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out wordsnumber) ||
       wordsnumber < 0 || wordsnumber > 20)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("*Leader Instructor: You must follow my instructions !");
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.Write("Enter the number of words (1 - 20): ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a word into a list with `words.Add(wordsnumber);`. After adding a word into a list you can iterate through the list with a `for` loop and then ad `if` statement for comparing your words like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        //so you don't compare the word with itself
        if (i != j) {
            if (words[i] == words[j]) {
                ...words are the same do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also as [@Rufus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2052655/rufus-l) said try using `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`